# 3 out of 5 appendices missing

Tags: appendices

EDIT: This problem has been solved. It was as easy as this: one of the appendices had an `\end{document}`due to a copy-paste mistake. So if you ever have this problem, search for something like that. I apologize for any time wasted on problem solving here guys...

I have a problem including appendices in my latex article. When I compile, just 2 of the 5 appendices I have included in the code are actually included in the pdf. Both the text and the TOC are missing from the 3 last appendices. TexShop compiles without complaints.

The code used are:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,english,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx, tabularx, amssymb, amsmath, wasysymb, booktabs, url, fancyhdr}
\usepackage{appendix, enumerate, geometry, parskip, cite}
\usepackage[hang,small,bf]{caption}
\usepackage{geometry, parskip}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

%Document contents

%------------- The Bibliography -------------
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
\newpage
\bibliography{Bibliography/ref}
\bibliographystyle{plain}   %unsrt

%------------- Appendices -------------
\newpage
\appendix
\addappheadtotoc

\input Appendices/appendix_group-logs
\input Appendices/appendix_spgr-task
\input Appendices/appendix_group-contract
\input Appendices/appendix_group-contract-revised
\input Appendices/appendix_group-agreement

\end{document}
```

Does somebody have an idea about what's going on? Thanks in advance! =)

Comment: First of all try using braces: `\input{Appendices/...}`

Comment: Yup, tried it. Didn't do the trick...

Comment: Look at what the `.log` file says. However, it's possible that the second appendix file contains `\end{document}`

Comment: You were absolutely right, my man!

Comment: The question has been closed as "too localized", which doesn't mean it was a bad question.